# Execution failed for task: app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug

Tags: android

Here is my app `lvl gradle`, I get this error when I test my tablet which is `API 19` what is the problem?

```
ERROR:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'. > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/hardware/display/DisplayManagerCompat$JellybeanMr1Impl.class

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android 
{
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
    defaultConfig 
    {
        applicationId "com.example.batintaskin.fcmwithappserver"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes 
    {
        release 
        {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies 
{
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```